# Should I manually insert my id back into the object I've just inserted

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In my meteor app, I'm inserting a document into my database

```
    meeting =
        name: team.name
        time: new Date()
        active: true
        team:
            id: team._id
            name: team.name
        cards: cards


    id = share.Meetings.insert meeting
```

Immediately afterwards, I'm calling another function passing the object I've inserted

```
    SendAlertOut(meeting)
```

I have noticed that the meeting object doesn't have the _id populated. This is because mongodb simply returns the _id.

I'm wondering is it better practice to just manually populate the id like this

```
    id = share.Meetings.insert meeting

    meeting._id = id

    SendAlertOut(meeting)
```

Or should I actually grab the object back out of the database?

```
    id = share.Meetings.insert meeting

    meeting._id = share.Meetings.find({_id : id})

    SendAlertOut(meeting)
```

Would manually populating the returned id into the document be just the same as grabbing the whole object back from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the insert callback in order to populate the id for the meeting; that way you can avoid a second call to the database, but you are also guaranteed that the id is defined. Thus, it should be something like:

```
Meetings.insert(meeting, function(err, result) {
     if (err)
       alert('error')
     else {
       meeting._id = result
       SendAlertOut(meeting)
     }
})
```